# WP7.1 app will not deploy to WP8 Device

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a wp7.1 app that I am compiling in vs 2012. I can deploy to the Wp7 and Wp8 emulators but i cannot deploy to my HTC 8x (WP8 device). I can also deploy the app to an old 7.1 device.

I am able to deploy an empty project to the Wp8 device.

The error i get is:

> Installation of the application failed. Run time error has occurred.
>   Fix the Capabilities in WMAppManifest.xml file.

The capabilities have not changed since it was compiling in Vs2010.

Any ideas what this could be?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575955/what-is-the-correct-way-to-manage-app-capabilities-listed-in-the-wmappmanifest

Comment: Sadly not but thanks anyway

Comment: I voted both answers up but selected gregstoll because: gregstoll-the brute force approach of turning them all off (cleared out any incorrect ones) and back on again worked. justinangel-because ye that old capability was in there but removing just that did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try just turning all the Capabilities on and seeing if that fixes it.  If it does, you can start turning off ones you don't need.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like someone at HTC dropped the ball on deploying WP7.1 apps to HTC 8X. This scenario works fine on Lumia phones.

Anyway, it's probably because some of WP7.5 capabilities were deprecated in favour of new WP8 capabilities. Specifically ID_CAP_MEDIALIB were deprecated in faovur of ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_AUDIO, ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO, ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_VIDEO and ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PLAYBACK. Removing that capability and replacing it with the new ones might solve your problem. When

See complete list of WP8 caps @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206936(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: That is quite a big ball to drop. The app does install on device via the store. I will try your suggestion when i am back at pc tonight

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem due to `<Capability Name="ID_CAP_NETWORKING_ADMIN" />` presence and missing

```
<ScreenResolution Name="ID_RESOLUTION_WXGA"/>
```

If you follow this steps it should solve all the problems:

1) remove any capability which is not specified for your target wp at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206936%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

2) add the default ones. Pay attention to ID_CAP_MEDIALIB, which has changed and it requires to specify in more detail what you need. As example, in my project I have:

```
<Capability Name="ID_CAP_NETWORKING" />
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_LOCATION" />
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_SENSORS" />
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MICROPHONE" />
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PLAYBACK" />
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_GAMERSERVICES" />
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_PHONEDIALER" />
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_PUSH_NOTIFICATION" />
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT" />


  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_IDENTITY_DEVICE"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_IDENTITY_USER"/>

  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_ISV_CAMERA"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_CONTACTS"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_APPOINTMENTS"/>
```

3) make sure that you have the proper resolution enabled,  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769509%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_SCREENRESOLUTIONSelement

```
<ScreenResolutions>
  <ScreenResolution Name="ID_RESOLUTION_WVGA"/>
  <ScreenResolution Name="ID_RESOLUTION_WXGA"/>
  <ScreenResolution Name="ID_RESOLUTION_HD720P"/>
</ScreenResolutions>
```

Comment: The ScreenResolution fixed it for me. I had only 2 of them. Thanks!